# Using Arial and special characters

Tags: symbols, characters, arial

I have to use Arial in my document. If I want to use special characters in the text, such as numbers set higher or lower, these are not displayed or are only displayed as a rectangle.Superscript 2(²) is working.

If I try it in math mode, I get the characters displayed, but with serifs (different font?!). This is okay for formulas, but not for body text.

What is the best practice to display these characters in Arial in body text? I use Overleaf and XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Arial} 
\Large
This ² is ⁴ a ₂ Text.
This $^2$ is $^4$ a $_{2}$ Text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textsuperscript{2}`

Comment: on windows arial contains the ⁴ too, (but not the ₂).  Generally the support for such real script chars is rather patchy. \textsuperscript is safer.

Comment: Try Arial Unicode MS also available on windows, has a wider range of  unicode glyphs.

Answer (score 4):

The superscript characters are in a current version of Arial on windows, but not subscript, however you can use `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript` to use scaled versions of the test font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Arial} 
\Large
This ² is ⁴ a ₂ Text.

This $^2$ is $^4$ a $_{2}$ Text.

This \textsuperscript{2} is \textsuperscript{4} is a \textsubscript{2} Text.
\end{document}
```